# Images not scaling on devices

Tags: html, css, ipad, scaling, device

I'm really struggling with the homepage of [my website](http://www.laurenwomack.com).

The images saying Animation and Interactive, Web Design, Print Design and Illustration look fine on my computer, but when I look at my site on my iPad they aren't scaling properly.

Here is the CSS:

```
#content { 
   position: relative;
   color: #333;
   width:100%;
   min-width: 900px;
   border:none;
   background: none;
   overflow:auto;
   padding-right:32px;
   padding-left:32px;
   padding-bottom: 86px;
}
#slideshow {
   position:relative;
   height:462px;
   z-index:-1;
}
#slideshow IMG {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:8;
}
#slideshow IMG.active {
   z-index:10;
}
#slideshow IMG.last-active {
   z-index:9;
}
#rightholder {
   float: right;
   clear: left;
   max-width: 639px;
   width: 60%;
   padding-top: 90px;   
   z-index:11;
}
.right {
   float:right;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   max-width: 50%;
   z-index:13;
}
.left{
   float:left;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   max-width: 50%;
   z-index:12;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean they don't scale on iPad? there is no css on them to make them scale.

Comment: They're all fixed dimension images so they wouldn't. You want to set the dimensions in the CSS.

Comment: I defined the dimensions in the html, I'll try doing it in the CSS. Thanks

Here's the HTML:
    <a href="illustration.html"><img src="images/index/illustration.png"width="307" height="118" max-width="100%" alt="Illustration"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but I believe your problem mainly comes from some of your `min-width` and `max-width` properties that constraint the page when resizing.

If you're using flexible units, you should try to let the layout be as fluid as possible. I'm guessing you're using these properties to prevent odd behaviors, for that you should rather use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/) to adapt your design to various resolutions.

You should also make sure you don't set fixed sizes to your images (either in your CSS or HTML documents). Instead, use `img { max-width: 100%; }`.

Hope it helps.